# Send global copy/paste menu action to child widget

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside2

I have an application with various child widgets (qlineedits, qtextedits, qtreeview, etc).

These support copy and paste using their built-in methods or a custom copy (captured `keyPressEvent` for `QKeySequence.Copy`). This all works fine when I use the keyboard shortcuts. I thought that I could add menu items for Copy and Paste but it's not clear to me how to get these to trigger the copy/paste actions of the child widget.

Would I need to pass the action to the `focusWidget()` somehow or is there a better way that I am missing? Bear in mind that I have custom copy methods for some widgets.

Comment: Better design is to catch state changing of one widget, and edit text in anothers. Use `focusWidget` for this is not a good idea

Comment: A global copy/paste seems like poor design. Usually, the menu-bar copy/paste only applies to the core functionality of the application: e.g. the edit-control of a text editor. Subsidiary widgets should have their own context-menu and built-in shortucts for handling copy/paste. As a user, it would be very confusing for it to work any other way. I'd be surprised if there's many (or even *any*) other applications that have the sort of global copy/paste that is suggested in the question.

Comment: "Subsidiary widgets should have their own context-menu and built-in shortucts for handling copy/paste." - that's essentially what I currently have. I had assumed that users would want a 'global' copy that would trigger the child widgets copy. Huh, never really thought about it as everything I interact with has the global copy but, I guess (as you say), it has one core function too (like word processor, spreadsheet, etc)!

Comment: @SimpleOne it's important to consider the aspect of *context*. As long as the user has a clear clue about the action they're going to trigger, there shouldn't be any confusion. Normally, that *clue* is visual (a focused widget shows a highlighted border) or assumed by the context (the user clicked somewhere), but if none of them is clear to the user, no assumptions should be made, unless a "default" result is made clear by some means. Generic clipboard operations work fine in your examples because they assume a basic behavior. If that behavior isn't clear, then something's wrong with the UI.